# Does SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 2 Apply to SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, servicepacks

I've been using SQL Server 2008 R2 for my development. I noticed that service pack 2 for SQL Server 2008 just came out. However, I checked [here](http://support.microsoft.com/sp) and Microsoft does not provide a link to any of the service packs for SQL Server 2008 R2. So it is not clear to me whether or not I should apply their service pack to my instance of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Do I need to apply some version of service pack 2 to my instance of SQL Server 2008 R2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, SP2 for SQL 2008 cannot be applied to SQL 2008 R2, they are different product versions.

[Here's the 2008 SP2 announcement](https://web.archive.org/web/20150930054022/http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2010/09/29/sql-server-2008-sp2-is-available-for-download-today.aspx).
In addition to some bug fixes, it does contain some updates that make it *compatible with some SQL 2008 R2 features*, but this patch can't be applied to R2.

The current patch level for SQL 2008 R2 is Cumulative Update 3 ([Announcement](https://web.archive.org/web/20141231192505/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2010/08/16/cumulative-update-3-for-sql-server-2008-r2-rtm.aspx), [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb2261464-cumulative-update-package-3-for-sql-server-2008-r2-53037506-a9af-4780-e32a-8d4ef5be3d6e)).